# Removing all indices that contain NaNs across a particular dimension in PyTorch Tensor

Tags: numpy, pytorch, nan, tensor-indexing

I have a `torch` tensor of the following form:

```
a = torch.tensor([[[2,3],
                   [3,4],
                   [4,5]],
                  [[3,6],
                   [6,2],
                   [2,-1]],
                  [[float('nan'), 1],
                   [2,3], 
                   [3,2]])
```

I would like to return another tensor with `nan` removed, but also all the entries along the same dimension removed. So expect

```
 a_clean =    torch.tensor([[[3,4],
                       [4,5]],
                      [[6,2],
                       [2,-1]],
                      [[2,3], 
                       [3,2]])
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: @Brian I think the link you shared doesn’t apply to the example OP has shared.

Comment: @titanium Thanks for catching that! I retracted the dupe

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using [`Tensor.isnan`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.isnan.html#torch.Tensor.isnan), [`Tensor.any`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.any.html#torch.Tensor.any), and some creative indexing:

```
>>> a[:, ~a.isnan().any(dim=2).any(dim=0), :]
tensor([[[ 3.,  4.],
         [ 4.,  5.]],
        [[ 6.,  2.],
         [ 2., -1.]],
        [[ 2.,  3.],
         [ 3.,  2.]]])
```

Note that you're trying to remove entries across dimension `1`, so the indexing takes place in dimension `1`. Reducing the result of `isnan()` across every dimension except dimension `1` tells us which indices in dimension `1` contain NaN values. Putting these together gives the expression above.